# Best way to perform bulk insert SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a tabled called `products`

which has following columns
`id`, `product_id`, `data`, `activity_id`

What I am essentially trying to do is copy bulk of existing products and update it's `activity_id` and create new entry in the products table.
Example:

I already have 70 existing entries in products with activity_id 2

Now I want to create another 70 entries with same data except for updated `activity_id`

I could have thousands of existing entries that I'd like to make a copy of and update the copied entries activity_id to be a new id.

```
products = self.session.query(model.Products).filter(filter1, filter2).all()
```

This returns all the existing products for a filter.

Then I iterate through products, then simply clone existing products and just update activity_id field.

```
 for product in products:
                product.activity_id = new_id

 self.uow.skus.bulk_save_objects(simulation_skus)
 self.uow.flush()
 self.uow.commit()
```

What is the best/ fastest way to do these bulk entries so it kills time, as of now it's OK performance, is there a better solution?

Comment: I have undeleted this question because I put a fair amount of work into answering you. I did that because I thought this was something worth showing to more people with similar problems. That’s the goal of this site: to share solutions. Don’t deprive others of the help you received here.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to load these objects locally, all you really want to do is have the *database* create these rows.

You essentially want to run a query that creates the rows from the existing rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO product (product_id, data, activity_id)
SELECT product_id, data, 2  -- the new activity_id value
FROM product
WHERE activity_id = old_id
```

The above query would run entirely on the database server; this is far preferable over loading your query into Python objects, then sending all the Python data back to the server to populate `INSERT` statements for each new row.

Queries like that are something you could do with [SQLAlchemy *core*](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/index.html), the half of the API that deals with generating SQL statements. However, you *can* use a query built from a [declarative ORM model](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/orm/extensions/declarative/index.html) as a starting point. You'd need to

1. Access the [`Table` instance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) for the model, as that then lets you create an `INSERT` statement via the [`Table.insert()` method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.insert).
   You could also get the same object from `models.Product` query, more on that later.
2. Access the statement that would normally fetch the data for your Python instances for your filtered `models.Product` query; you can do so via the [`Query.statement` property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.statement).
3. Update the statement to replace the included `activity_id` column with your new value, and remove the primary key (I'm assuming that you have an auto-incrementing primary key column).
4. Apply that updated statement to the `Insert` object for the table via [`Insert.from_select()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.from_select).
5. Execute the generated `INSERT INTO ... FROM ...` query.

Step 1 can be achieved by using the [SQLAlchemy introspection API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/inspection.html); the [`inspect()` function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/inspection.html#sqlalchemy.inspect), applied to a model class, gives you a [`Mapper` instance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Mapper), which in turn has a [`Mapper.local_table` attribute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Mapper.local_table).

Steps 2 and 3 require a little juggling with the [`Select.with_only_columns()` method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns) to produce a new `SELECT` statement where we swapped out the column. You can't easily *remove* a column from a select statement but we can, however, use a loop over the [existing columns in the query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.columns) to 'copy' them across to the new `SELECT`, and at the same time make our replacement.

Step 4 is then straightforward, `Insert.from_select()` needs to have the columns that are inserted and the `SELECT` query. We have both as the `SELECT` object we have gives us its columns too.

Here is the code for generating your `INSERT`; the `**replace` keyword arguments are the columns you want to replace when inserting:

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect, literal
from sqlalchemy.sql import ClauseElement

def insert_from_query(model, query, **replace):
    # The SQLAlchemy core definition of the table
    table = inspect(model).local_table
    # and the underlying core select statement to source new rows from
    select = query.statement

    # validate asssumptions: make sure the query produces rows from the above table
    assert table in select.froms, f"{query!r} must produce rows from {model!r}"
    assert all(c.name in select.columns for c in table.columns), f"{query!r} must include all {model!r} columns"

    # updated select, replacing the indicated columns
    as_clause = lambda v: literal(v) if not isinstance(v, ClauseElement) else v
    replacements = {name: as_clause(value).label(name) for name, value in replace.items()}
    from_select = select.with_only_columns([
        replacements.get(c.name, c)
        for c in table.columns
        if not c.primary_key
    ])
        
    return table.insert().from_select(from_select.columns, from_select)
```

I included a few assertions about the model and query relationship, and the code accepts arbitrary column clauses as replacements, not just literal values. You could use `func.max(models.Product.activity_id) + 1` as a replacement value (wrapped as a subselect), for example.

The above function executes steps 1-4, producing the desired `INSERT` SQL statement when printed (I created a `products` model and query that I thought might be representative):

```py
>>> print(insert_from_query(models.Product, products, activity_id=2))
INSERT INTO products (product_id, data, activity_id) SELECT products.product_id, products.data, :param_1 AS activity_id
FROM products
WHERE products.activity_id != :activity_id_1
```

All you have to do is execute it:

```py
insert_stmt = insert_from_query(models.Product, products, activity_id=2)
self.session.execute(insert_stmt)
```

Comment: @HOOOPLA: updated to filter out the primary key now.

Comment: Got it, let me give that a shot.

Comment: @HOOOPLA given that you posted a new question with the *old, broken version*: you didn’t appear to have given my corrected code a shot. Please try again.