# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_pkey"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
def insert_from_query(self, model, query, **replace):
        # The SQLAlchemy core definition of the table
        table = inspect(model).local_table
        # and the underlying core select statement to source new rows from
        print(type(query))
        select = query.statement

        # validate asssumptions: make sure the query produces rows from the above table
        assert table in select.froms, f"{query!r} must produce rows from {model!r}"
        assert all(c.name in select.columns for c in table.columns), f"{query!r} must include all {model!r} columns"

        # updated select, replacing the indicated columns
        as_clause = lambda v: literal(v) if not isinstance(v, ClauseElement) else v
        replacements = {name: as_clause(value).label(name) for name, value in replace.items()}
        from_select = select.with_only_columns([replacements.get(c.name, c) for c in table.columns])
            
        insert_statement = table.insert().from_select(from_select.columns, from_select)
        insert = self.engine.execute(insert_statement)
        return insert
```

I am trying to do mass insert whilst updating one field called 'activity_id' within product table.

The statement generated does that, however I ran into IntegrityError

Error Trace:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_pkey"    
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(210776) already exists.
```

I am basically making duplicates of existing entry, and just updating their activity_id, but when creating these cloned entries with one updated field `activity_id`, I think it should also increment the field `id`, I think it tries to clone that field right now. In my db it's marked as primary key/ index.

Comment: You seem to have missed that I already adjusted my answer to account for this issue: you need to use the updated revision that also filters out the primary key.

Comment: @rfkortekaas they are not upserting, no. My initial revision of my [answer to their previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66399992) simply forgot to exclude the Primary Key from the generated insert and select statement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks! I didn't read close enough that he was duplicating from the same table. Indeed filtering out Primary Key is the best solution! I've upvoted your answer on the other question